# How to update status with custom appid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app.
I want to update users status from this app, with another app id, because I have to customize the via param.

I try this code:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: status, application: xxxxxxxxxxxxx }
```

But doesn't work.

I know it is possible to customize via param by user this way:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?preview=true&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How can I do this from my app?

Comment: You can also change name of your application

Comment: I know, but this is the joke of the story :)